# Python tkinter displaying images as movie stream

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to screen-grab and display the image quickly like a recording. It seems to all function well except the display window is "blinking" occasionally with a white frame. It doesn't appear to be every update or every other frame, but rather every 5 or so. Any thoughts on the cause?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab, ImageTk
import threading
from collections import deque
from io import BytesIO

class buildFrame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.land = Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=600)
        self.land.pack()
        self.genObj()
        self.thsObj = self.land.create_image(0,0, anchor='nw', image=self.imgObj)
        self.sStream = deque()
        self.spinning = True

        prQ = threading.Thread(target=self.procQ)
        prQ.start()

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.snapS, args=[100])
        t1.start()

    def genObj(self):
        tmp = Image.new('RGBA', (800, 600), color=(0, 0, 0))
        self.imgObj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=tmp)

    def procQ(self):
        while self.spinning == True:
            if self.sStream:
                self.land.itemconfig(self.thsObj, image=self.sStream[0])
                self.sStream.popleft()

    def snapS(self, shtCount):
        quality_val = 70

        for i in range(shtCount):
            mem_file = BytesIO()
            ImageGrab.grab().save(mem_file, format="JPEG", quality=quality_val)
            mem_file.seek(0)
            tmp = Image.open(mem_file)
            tmp.thumbnail([800, 600])
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tmp)
            self.sStream.append(img)

        mem_file.close()



world = buildFrame()
world.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid making Tk calls on non GUI threads. This works much more smoothly if you get rid of the threads entirely and use `after` to schedule the image capture.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO

class buildFrame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.land = Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=600)
        self.land.pack()
        tmp = Image.new('RGBA', (800, 600), color=(0, 0, 0))
        self.imgObj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=tmp)
        self.thsObj = self.land.create_image(0,0, anchor='nw', image=self.imgObj)
        self.root.after("idle", self.snapS)

    def snapS(self):
        quality_val = 70
        mem_file = BytesIO()
        ImageGrab.grab().save(mem_file, format="JPEG", quality=quality_val)
        mem_file.seek(0)
        tmp = Image.open(mem_file)
        tmp.thumbnail([800, 600])
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tmp)
        self.land.itemconfig(self.thsObj, image=self.image)
        mem_file.close()
        self.root.after(10, self.snapS)

world = buildFrame()
world.root.mainloop()
```

If you really want to use threads, you should queue the image stream and have the UI thread deserialize the tkinter image from the stream and display it. So one thread for capture and the main thread doing display.

### EDIT

The following version keeps using a thread for the capture and passes the data via the deque but ensures that only the Tk UI thread operates on Tk objects. This needs some work to avoid accumulating images in the queue but a delay of 100ms between images works fine for now.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab, ImageTk
import sys, threading, time
from collections import deque
from io import BytesIO

class buildFrame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_destroy)
        self.land = Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=600)
        self.land.pack()
        self.genObj()
        self.thsObj = self.land.create_image(0,0, anchor='nw', image=self.imgObj)
        self.sStream = deque()
        self.image_ready = threading.Event()
        self.spinning = True

        self.prQ = threading.Thread(target=self.procQ)
        self.prQ.start()

        self.t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.snapS, args=[100])
        self.t1.start()

    def on_destroy(self):
        self.spinning = False
        self.root.after_cancel(self.afterid)
        self.prQ.join()
        self.t1.join()
        self.root.destroy()

    def genObj(self):
        tmp = Image.new('RGBA', (800, 600), color=(0, 0, 0))
        self.imgObj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=tmp)

    def procQ(self):
        while self.spinning == True:
            if self.image_ready.wait(0.1):
                print(len(self.sStream))
                self.image_ready.clear()
                self.afterid = self.root.after(1, self.show_image)

    def show_image(self):
        stream = self.sStream[0]
        self.sStream.popleft()
        tmp = Image.open(stream)
        tmp.thumbnail([800, 600])
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tmp)
        self.land.itemconfig(self.thsObj, image=self.image)
        stream.close()

    def snapS(self, shtCount):
        quality_val = 70

        while self.spinning:
            mem_file = BytesIO()
            ImageGrab.grab().save(mem_file, format="JPEG", quality=quality_val)
            mem_file.seek(0)
            self.sStream.append(mem_file)
            self.image_ready.set()
            time.sleep(0.1)

def main():
    world = buildFrame()
    world.root.mainloop()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: "you should queue the image stream and have the UI thread deserialize the tkinter image from the stream and display it."

Isn't that what i was doing here?
self.sStream = deque()
            self.sStream.append(img)

Comment: you stated I should avoid making threads inside the tkinter mainloop thread. Is there specific reasons why? I am asking sincerely because I don't know. I did this because I want the images from the remote system to continue while the app is able to continue receiving mouse and keyboard commands. the other thread is just checking the queue for new images and then popping [0]. I predict there will be 4 total threads. on top of the gui in order to have a remote presence. 

Is there a better way to maintain code running alongside the tkinter mainloop that can still draw to the canvas?

Comment: When you queue the tkimage, you are just putting the name of the image onto the deque. You have already created the image itself. You can pass the image data using `self.sStream.append(mem_file)`. The reader thread can then post a Tk event to have the Tk image created and displayed by the UI thread. See edited code.